# FullCalendar Custom Month view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working on refreshing a project that utilised FullCalendar 2.0 but I think it was modified.

From what I can see - unfortunately no documentation - Extra options were implemented: `startOfMonth = 24`, `monthAdvance = true` and `hdrPrefix = 'Claim Month: '`.

The option `startOfMonth = 24` gives a month view starting on the 24th of the month and ending on the 23rd of the following month. This is the company period for Overtime and the calendar is used to book overtime.

The `monthAdvance = true` option as far as I can see is used to change the Calendar title so that for the period beginning 24th Dec 2016 it displays 'Claim Month: Jan 2017' as this period is known as Jan pay period. Setting the `monthAdvance` value to `false` gives 'Claim Month: Dec 2016'. The `hrdPrefix` is used here.

To have the calendar display as a normal month I just set the values to `startOfMonth = 1`, `monthAdvance = false` and `hdrPrefix = ''`.

My question is does the latest version of FullCalendar have this feature built in or has anyone made similar amendments to the latest version and is willing to share.

I have not found any mention in Documentation and other searches I've made.

Comment: Have you reviewed a diff of the customized fullcalendar vs original release version on which it was based? That would give an idea of what all was changed and may allow porting to a newer version if needed.

Comment: I have that's where I found the new options... there were also some changes to moment.add where the parameters were swapped around from add('day', 1) to add(1, 'day') around 30 different changes in all. I was just wondering if the newest version already had such a feature...